# how do I check index of my file when I do certain operations C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Hello I have a list of recipes (they are all file.dat).
In my software I can do certain operations, like `"copy"`, `"rename"`, `"create new recipe"` and `"delete"`.
The structure name of these files is always `date_index_nameOfRecipe.dat` and they are all sorted by index.

For example I have 3 files:

- `date_1_name.dat`
- `date_2_name.dat`
- `date_3_name.dat`

And if I want to copy the second one it becomes `date_3_name.dat` but I already have a file with index=3 and when I sort the list it creates conflict. The same goes with the function `"rename"` and `"create new recipe"`. How can I solve this problem?

This is the function I use when I click on `"copy"`:

```
    private void buttonCopy_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
       _filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(_folder, "*.dat");
       numberOfRecipes = _filePaths.Length;
       indexCopy = numberOfRecipes + 1
    }
```

this is what I do when I copy the file:

```
string index = indexCopy.ToString();
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss_");
string nameDef = date + index + "_" + this.tbNewCopy.Text + ".dat";
string folder = ManageForm.ManageForm.formChooseRecipe.Folder;
_nameFileDestinationWithPath = folder + @"\" + nameDef;

string[] st = ManageForm.ManageForm.formChooseRecipe.FilePaths;
int num = st.Length;
string name = "";
string nameData = "";
string nameToPass = "";
int ind = -1;
bool fileExist = false;

for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(st[i]);
    nameData = name;
    ind = name.LastIndexOf("_");
    name = name.Substring(ind + 1, (name.Length - ind - 1));

    if (name == this.tbNewCopy.Text)
    {
        fileExist = true;
        ind = i;
        nameToPass = nameData + ".dat";
        break;
    }
}


if (!fileExist)
{
    try
    {
        File.Copy(_nomeFileOrigin, _nameFileDestinationWithPath);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string s = ex.Message;
    }
}
else
{ 
    //SHOW POPUP Overwrite file copied
    FormPopupOverwriteFileCopy formShowDialog = new FormPopupOverwriteFileCopy();
    //Show testDialog as a modal dialog and determine if DialogResult = OK.

    if (formShowDialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
    {
        if (formShowDialog.ChooseOverwrite)
        {
            try
            {           
                File.Copy(_nomeFileOrigin, _nameFileDestinationWithPath, true);
                ManageForm.ManageForm.formChooseRecipe.overwritten = true;
                File.Delete(_nomeFileOrigin);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string s = ex.Message;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //chosen to not overwrite, setting destination name = origin name
            ManageForm.ManageForm.formChooseRecipe.overwritten = true;    
            _nameFileDestinationWithPath = _nameFileOrigine;   
        }

        formShowDialog.Dispose();
    }
}
```

and this is the function I use for sorting:

```
public string[] SortArray(string[] recipes)
        {
            string[] sorted = new string[recipes.Length];
            foreach (string r in recipes)
            {
                int index = new ComparableRecipe(r).IndexPart;
                if (index != Int32.MaxValue)
                {
                    if (index >= 1)
                    {
                        sorted[index - 1] = r; // top
                    }
                }
            }

            return sorted;
        }
```

Comment: Is there an Exception? What is the actual outcome? and what is the desired outcome?

Comment: What do you want to happen? Seems like you need a more robust naming strategy?

Comment: You'll need to keep track of the indexes used, and use the next unused index (or simply the last index used + 1) when copying/renaming/creating items.

Comment: the problem is that when I have two files with the same index, it returns two file but one is null and I have a nullexception in a particular part of the software. But the problem starts when I sort two file with the same index. So I'd like a solution for this

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes I'd like to do that but how?

Comment: Create a variable that represents the last index used (`lastIndexUsed`). When you need a new file, get the number from `lastIndexUsed` and add one. Then, increment `lastIndexUsed` by one. Initialize it by sorting and getting the number from the last item in the list (or sort in reverse order and get the first).